# including a config file from server to localhost

Tags: php, mysql

i am developing one of my clients site and i want to include config.php to my localhost ( the config.php file is located in www.client-domain.com ).

is there any way to let me include this file localy to help me developing the site without upload and test each file.

i used this

```
<?php
include "/home/myclints/public_html/book/config.php";
?>
```

but it dosnt work.

the config file contain

```
$dbhost="localhost";
$dbname="books";
$dbuname="books_user";
$dbpass="123";
$dbconnect=mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuname,$dbpass) or die ("Could not connect to MySQL");

$dd=mysql_select_db($dbname) or die ("Could not select database");
```

i want to display data from my client site into my localhost.

regards
Al3in

Answer (score 0):

If the config.php is located in a publicly accessible place, I suppose you can use file_get_contents() and eval()...

though include() will work if you have url wrappers enabled (and the file is still in a publicly accessible place).. you would point to it like http://www.site.com/path/to/config.php

Comment: the config file contain ( mysql variables )

Comment: what do you mean by "mysql variables"?  do you mean like $db="db name"; $host = "localhost"; $table="table name"; etc..? those are php variables that you pass to php functions or use in query strings that you also use php functions to pass to mysql. Point is, they are php variables.

Comment: yes they are .. and i am developing a site in localhost and i want to fetch the data from my client's site direct.

Comment: okay well is config.php in a publicly accessible directory? As in, can you go to http://www.site.com/path/to/config.php ? Then try using the absolute (public) url in your include.

Comment: well them I'm afraid you're SoL. You will have to develop on the server where it can access the file or else make your own local copy and point to the correct local path/to/config.php

Answer (score 0):

don't know wheter I understood you right, but you want to include a file from the internet to your local application? If you've got an internet connection there's no problem.

```
<?php
  include 'www.domain.de/config.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the server is reasonably configured, you shouldn't be able to. If you request the file, it will be parsed through PHP and in this particular example output either nothing or one of the "die" messages. The file path is wrong, too - you cannot include a file on a remote server by using just the path the file has on the server, it isn't even specified which server to look at!

Anyway, unless you have a database with the exact same configuration (db login, db user and db password) running on your own computer, it will definitely not work, because localhost on your machine means your own computer, but localhost on the server means the server. If you wish to connect to the server's database, you will have to have your own configuration file with connection details for the server where the host will be the real server name (if it - both the server and the database user - even has remote connections allowed).